# multiplying all combinations of columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to find an efficient way of multiplying each column combination within a pandas dataframe.  I have managed to achieve this with itertools, however when the size of the dataframe increases it dramatically slows down.  I am going to need to perform this on a dataframe with a size of about (100,1000)

Example of working code with smaller dataframe below,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 10))
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

for p in combinations_with_replacement(df.columns,2):
        title = p
        new_df[title] = df[p[0]]*df[p[1]]
```

Does anybody have any suggestions on how this could be achieved?

Comment: I guess it has to be `O(n^2)` complexity since no calculation can be saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining index view and `array.prod(axis)`, this runs ~100 times faster:

```
def f1():
    #with loop
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for p in combinations_with_replacement(df.columns,2):
            title = p
            new_df[title] = df[p[0]]*df[p[1]]
    return new_df

def f2():
    n = len(df.columns)
    ix = np.indices((n,n))[:, ~np.tri(n, k=-1, dtype=bool)]
    return pd.DataFrame(df.values.T[ix.T].prod(1).T, columns=list(map(tuple, ix.T)))
```

Comment: In instances where the dataframe has column values that aren't just the index location, how do I set the new column headers to show the results of what has been multiplied.

For example, if the df is as follows;

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 10), columns=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','j','k'])

I would want to see ('a', 'b') as a column, rather than (0,1)

Comment: Use `columns = list(map(tuple, np.array(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','j','k'])[ix.T]))`. Note the `list(map(tuple` is just for creating tuples for column headers, the `np.array(...)[ix.T]` is for creating the array of letter combinations.